Bluepill board gets programmed through Arduino IDE but not using Keil, chip ID:0x2BA01477
I am trying to program STM32 Blue pill board using Keil, and it gives the following error:
"Connection refused due to device mismatch; Device connected to debug unit is different from device selected for project target STMicroelectronics STM32F103C8."
I am using ST-Link debugger for programming as it does not have on-board ST-debugger. The issue is that it reads chip ID:0x2BA01477, which, I have read on other forums, is the ID read when your board uses clone instead of real STM32F103C8T6. Still, I want to program it using Keil. When I program the same setup using Arduino IDE, it is gets programmed in a perfectly fine way. Is there any other way to resolve this error in Keil using the same board or there is no other option left but to replace the board?
